# syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''

Tags: cygwin, syntax-error, token, biometrics

I'm trying to compile the NIST Biometric Image Software, and I have been having trouble all day. I finally got the source checked out right, and I installed cygwin with no problems (I have used it in the past), but when I went to compile, I get this error:

```
 $  sh setup.sh </cygdrive/c/NBIS> [--without-X11]
 setup.sh: line 94: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
 'etup.sh: line 94: `    case $1 in
```

Now I'm sure any advanced coder would head to the setup.sh and look for problems, but I'm not really much of a coder (I'm only compiling this because there are no pre-compiled packages) so I don't know what to do. I didn't install any libraries with cygwin, I just left everything default. I'm trying to follow the NBIS manual, but I don't really understand it that well and so I'm struggling badly. Maybye taking a look at it you may notice something I missed: http://www.nist.gov/customcf/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=51097

Comment: Everyone here seems to suggest that the answer is to use linux style newlines, anyone know what to do if you need to run a bash script with windows style newlines?

Comment: You know the line. You know the problem (a carriage return character after the word`in`). Why don't you just have a look at the file using a decent hex editor? BTW, @Groostav: I'm not convinced that the problem here is simply a script with CRLF line endings. If this were the case, it would more likely  have already bailed out already earlier.

Answer (score 94):

run

```
sed -i 's/\r//' setup.sh
```

to fix your line endings

Comment: sed -i 's/\r//' setup.sh
works!!

Answer (score 75):

That's a symptom of line-ending mismatch.

To convert `setup.sh` to Unix line endings on Cygwin, use

```
dos2unix setup.sh
```

Answer (score 19):

Easy way to convert example.sh file to unix is use NotePad++  (Edit>EOL Conversion>UNIX/OSX Format)

You can also set the default EOL in notepad++ (Settings>Preferences>New Document/Default Directory>select Unix/OSX under the Format box)

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. I encountered this as I was compiling Shell scripts on Linux Ubuntu Subsystem in Windows 10 but typing the commands in notepad++ instead of vim or via nano.

Answer (score 17):

In pycharm you can quickly change the line endings by clicking on the letters `CRLF` at the bottom right of the screen and selecting `LF`.

[image: pycharm line endings location]

Comment: Yes it's the fast way to change CRLF to LF using VS Code

Comment: It also works on PHPStorm, then a composer build is enought.

Comment: Yeah, it works for any Jetbrains IDE that I am aware of (IntelliJ, WebStorm, PHPStorm, PyCharm, etc.)

Answer (score 12):

Windows uses two characters (CR and LF, or `\r\n`) to mark the end of a line in a text file.  Unix, Linux, and (by default) Cygwin use a single LF or '\n' character.  Some Cygwin tools are able to deal with either format, but sh typically can't.

It looks like `setup.sh` uses Windows-style line endings -- or at least line 94 does.

I didn't find the download for the sources, but if they're distributed as a zip file, you might need to extract them using the Cygwin `unzip` command with the `-a` option, so any line endings are automatically converted.

But I suspect there's more to it than that.  The distributed `setup.sh` file shouldn't have had any Windows-style line endings in the first place, and if it did, I don't know why the problem wouldn't show up until line 94.

If you can post the URL for the source download, I'll take a look at `setup.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issue but I solved it using notepad++

Install Notepad++, Open your shell code using Notepad++, Go to the "Edit" menu, Select "EOL Conversion, Choose the "Unix (LF)" option and it should be fixed

or if you use Visual Studio Code you can change `CRLF` to `LF`

[Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrqL0.png)

[Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFdL9.png)