# Opensuse 13.1 build/envsetup.sh: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''

Tags: android, bash, shell, android-source, opensuse

I am working on android open source project. I have downloaded the latest release from android.googlesource.com.

Now, the git repository synching is complete. But, when I try to setup the environment for compiling android source code,the command: `source 'build/envsetup.sh'` 
is throwing this error:

**bash: build/envsetup.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'ash: build/envsetup.sh: line 1:`function hmm() {**

I have tried online solutions available but no success. If anyone knows how to fix this error, that would be helpful.

Comment: I have tried to follow the guidelines in your link. I hope it will help now to understand the problem.

Comment: looks like MS WIndows was involved creating file that is now being used in Linux environment. (`\r`).. `dos2unix file1 file2 file3 file.... filen` to convert/fix them all at once. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: the root cause of the problem was due to Git `autocrlf` set to `true`. Under Linux, it should be set to `input`:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

---

*(original answer)*

The problem comes from Windows end-of-lines (EOL) so you'll have to convert all scripts to unix-style EOL through `dos2unix` (run `apt-get install dos2unix` on Ubuntu) and then convert your scripts:

```
dos2unix build/envsetup.sh sdk/bash_completion/adb.bash
```

Then all `vendorsetup.sh` (that will prevent the "command not found" error you get):

```
find device/ -name vendorsetup.sh -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

And one last to run the `choosecombo` script:

```
dos2unix build/core/find-jdk-tools-jar.sh
```

EDIT: In order to finish the overall compilation, the exhaustive conversion:

```
find . -name '*.sh' -exec dos2unix {} \;
find . -name '*.py' -exec dos2unix {} \;
find . -name '*.c' -exec dos2unix {} \;
find . -name '*.h' -exec dos2unix {} \;
find . -name '*.cpp' -exec dos2unix {} \;
find . -name '*.hpp' -exec dos2unix {} \;
find . -name '*.txt' -exec dos2unix {} \;
find . -name 'Config.in' -exec dos2unix {} \;
find . -name 'Config.src' -exec dos2unix {} \;
find . -name 'Makefile' -exec dos2unix {} \;
find . -name 'mkmakefile' -exec dos2unix {} \;
find . -name 'Kconfig*' -exec dos2unix {} \;
find . -name rmtypedefs -exec dos2unix {} \;
find . -name apicheck -exec dos2unix {} \;
find . -name seapp_contexts -exec dos2unix {} \;
dos2unix external/busybox/scripts/* external/busybox/applets/* kernel/scripts/* dalvik/dx/etc/* prebuilts/sdk/tools/*
```

The `*.sh` for all shell scripts, and `*.py` for all python scripts (used during `make` compilation), as well as `.c` and `.cpp` file (obviously) and other files used by makefiles.

Of course you could go the over-overkill `find . -type f -exec dos2unix -s -k -o {} \;` and let `dos2unix` decide which files are text and which are binary.

There might be other. I'll edit this answer as I find new ones...

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to convert example.sh file to unix is use NotePad++ (Edit>EOL Conversion>UNIX/OSX Format)

You can also set the default EOL in notepad++ (Settings>Preferences>New Document/Default Directory>select Unix/OSX under the Format box)

Reference- [syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473766/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-in-r)

It also solves this problem: [android_build.sh gives error while building ffmpeg library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304121/android-build-sh-gives-error-while-building-ffmpeg-library/35623653#35623653)

I used this one. It solves my problem earlier.