# Build PJSIP for Android on Windows?

Tags: android, android-ndk, voip, pjsip

I am beginner with Android and I have to make a voip app and after searching I found that the better opensource library for that is PJSIP.
I download the below things to build the PJSIP library:

1. PJSIP from [here](http://www.pjsip.org/download.htm)
2. Android [NDK](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/ndk/downloads/index.html)
3. [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/download.html)

...But I don't know how to start. I checked this [link](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android) for the official PJSIP website but I didn't make any progress.

Which Directory do I have to put the Android NDK into?

How to use SWIG to build the PJSIP?!

Answer (score 2):

> which Directory i have to put the Android NDK ?

Put it where you want, later you will setup the path to it

```
$ export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/path_to_android_ndk_dir
```

> how to use SWIG to build the PJSIP ?!

You don't need SWIG to compile the PJSIP sources, it's needed only  if you want to build and and run the sample application PJSUA.

**Updated**

The steps to build sources are

1. Download sources from [PJSIP site](http://www.pjsip.org/download.htm). Pay attention if you will compile on Windows machine download `.zip` file, if on Unix machine (including OS X) then download `.bz2` file.
2. Go to `pjlib/include/pj/` from the downloaded sources. Create (or overwrite) a file called `config_site.h`. Copy the following code snippet

   > ```
   > #define PJ_CONFIG_ANDROID 1
   > #include <pj/config_site_sample.h>
   > ```
3. Open `Cmd` or `Terminal`
4. Go to pjsip root folder (the downloaded sources)

   `$ cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir`
5. Export bash var ANDROID_NDK_ROOT as a environment variable. Variable value should be the path of android ndk directory.

   `$ export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/path_to_android_ndk_dir` (Unix)

   `SET ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/path_to_android_ndk_dir` (Windows)
6. Perform build for target `armeabi`

   `$ ./configure-android`

If you need to perform build for
target `arm64-v8a` do `$ TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v8a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags`

target `armeabi-v7a` do `$ TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags`

target `x86` do `$ TARGET_ABI=x86 ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags`

7. Compile sources

   `$ make dep && make clean && make`

Comment: could you mention the steps to build the library ?

Comment: export is  a linux command and doesn't work on Windows! Is it possible to build pjsip for android using windows based systems?

Comment: SET ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/path_to_android_ndk_dir

Comment: Thanks export works as i'm now using cygwin(a windows based linux command prompt). running command `$ ./configure-android ` from pjproject-2.4.5/pjsip. results in following error!
-bash: ./configure-android: No such file or directory

Comment: Running the ./configure-android command on root of the project runs the command but gives error `/cygdrive/d/pjproject-2.4.5
$ ./configure-android
./configure-android: line 3: $'\r': command not found
./configure-android: line 5: $'\r': command not found
./configure-android: line 71: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/configure-android: line 71: `  for i in $NDK_OUT; do`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473766/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-in-r

Comment: thanks, Now i'm stuck on `$ make dep && make clean && make` Please check my logs https://paste.ee/p/O64gr